# Forth language EBNF rule for the while loop

Tags: ebnf, forth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forth language EBNF rule for an infinite loop or if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053030/forth-language-ebnf-rule-for-an-infinite-loop-or-if-statement)

Is there any [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) rule that describes a Forth while loop (or any other loop)?

Comment: Which one? A Forth `while` loop is like no other `while` loop in existence :-)

Answer (score 3):

`BEGIN <code> WHILE <code> REPEAT` — Executes the first `<code>` block and consumes whatever it leaves on top of the stack; if it's nonzero, the second `<code>` block is executed, and then everything starts over again.  If it's zero, execution skips to after the `REPEAT`.  Note that this can only be used inside a definition (e.g., "`: foo ... ;`").