# Forth language EBNF rule for an infinite loop or if statement

Tags: ebnf, forth

Is there an [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) rule that describes a Forth infinite loop or if statement?

Answer (score 4):

EBNF is used to describe *syntax*. A loop being infinite or otherwise wouldn't normally fall within what it would describe. As such, you'd be looking at the EBNF for an indefinite loop, which looks something like:

```
indefinite_loop ::= 'BEGIN' statements cond 'UNTIL'
```

Normally the `cond` will be something that pushes a 0 or 1 on the stack to determine whether to continue the loop (`0` means continue the loop, `1` means exit). As such, if you just insert a `0` directly, the loop will execute forever:

```
: infinite_loop BEGIN do_whatever 0 UNTIL ;
```

Comment: There is also the opposite construction:  BEGIN cond WHILE, in which 0 means exit, and 1 means continue the loop.  So : test BEGIN do_whatever 1 WHILE REPEAT ;

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
infinite_loop ::= 'BEGIN' statements 'AGAIN'
```

The `AGAIN` word is used to do an unconditional branch back to the `BEGIN`.  For example:

```
: main-loop BEGIN listen-for-event process-event AGAIN ;
```